# reducing looping execution time python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code for prefetcher but it is taking very much time in execution because of so many loops My input list is in prefetcher which is of length of 1000 how can I minimize my time. Thank you in advance

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a=iter(iterable)
    return itertools.zip_longest(a,a)

stride=0
newaddr=0
confidence=0
sub1=0
sub2=0
minimum=0
prefetchB=[]
for x,y in pairwise(prefetch):
    stride=abs(x-y)
    newaddr=x+stride
    prefetchBuf.append([x,stride,newaddr,confidence])
    for x in range(0,len(prefetchBuf)):
        for y in range(1,len(prefetchBuf)-1):
            for z in range(2,len(prefetchBuf)-2):
                if prefetchBuf[x][2]==prefetchBuf[y][0]:
                    if prefetchBuf[y][1]==0:
                        confidence+=1
                        prefetchBuf[x][-1]=confidence
                        if prefetchBuf[x][-1]==confiuser:
                            cacheArray[index]=prefetchBuf[x][2]
                    else:
                        stride=abs(z-y)
                        newaddr=y+stride
                        prefetchBuf[y][1]=stride
                        prefetchBuf[y][2]=newaddr
                else:
                    stride=abs(z-y)
                    newaddr=y+stride
                    prefetchBuf[y][1]=stride
                    prefetchBuf[y][2]=newaddr
```

Comment: what happened@Barmar

Comment: What do you mean? I simply cleaned up the code formatting.

Comment: Can you help me with reducing loops or execution time@Barmar. Sorry I am new to stack overflow Thank you for clarifying

Comment: It would help if you explained what this is supposed to do.

Comment: What is `confiuser`?

Comment: It looks like this is an `O(n**3)` algorithm, so it will necessarily be slow for large `n`.

Comment: confiuser is an argument given by the user to set the confidence value  it is mainly 2,4

Comment: My prefetchBuf is a 2d list and it changes values in its list in this loop but it is taking more time can i do any changes in the code to make it run faster

Comment: It's possible you might be able to improve it using pandas or numpy.

Comment: Put the clarifications in the question, not comments.

Comment: FYI, I don't expect to be able to answer this question.